# numpy composition of einsums?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

Suppose that I have a `np.einsum` that performs some calculation, and then pump that directly into yet another `np.einsum` to do some other thing.  Can I, in general, compose those two `einsum`s into a single `einsum`?

My specific use case is that I am doing a transpose, a matrix multiplication, and then another matrix multiplication to compute `b a^T a` :

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array

a = array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
b = array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])

matrix_multiply_by_transpose = 'ij,kj->ik'
matrix_multiply = 'ij,jk->ik'
test_answer = np.einsum(matrix_multiply,
    np.einsum(matrix_multiply_by_transpose, 
        b, a
    ),
    a
)

assert np.array_equal(test_answer, 
    np.einsum(an_answer_to_this_question, b, a, a))
#or, the ultimate most awesomest answer ever, if such a thing even exists
assert np.array_equal(test_answer,
    np.einsum(the_bestest_answer(matrix_multiply_by_transpose, matrix_multiply),
        b, a, a)
)
```

Comment: Throws exception at computation of `test_answer`.

Comment: Had the matrices swapped.  Is better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In single `einsum` call, it would be -

```
np.einsum('ij,kj,kl->il',b,a,a)
```

The intuition involved would be :

1. Start off from the innermost `einsum` call : `'ij,kj->ik'`.
2. Moving out, the second one is : `'ij,jk->ik'`. The first argument in it is the output from `step#1`. So, let's mould this argument for the second one based on the output from the first one, introducing new strings for new iterators : `'ik,kl->il'`. Note that `'kl'` is the second arg in this second `einsum` call, which is `a`.

Thus, combining, we have : `'ij,kj,kl->il'` with the inputs in the same sequence, i.e. `b,a` for the innermost `einsum` call and then `a` incoming as the third input.

Comment: I see that the `ij, kj` bit remained from the first multiply.  What is the reasoning that went on here?

Comment: Ah!  I see it.  :)

Comment: Yes, nested einsums may always be rewritten as a single statement, by associativity of the multilinear product. If it is a good idea performance-wise might depend on the particulars though. If one of the subterms is known to reduce to a small temporary, computing that temporary first might be more efficient, since einsum is not necessarily smart about doing that optimization itself. So if performance is indeed an issue, make sure to benchmark.

Comment: As a note with `optimize=True` einsum is quite smart about building intermediates and using BLAS when possible.