# Lazy evaluations of numpy.einsum to avoid storing intermediate large dimensional arrays in memory

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, lazy-evaluation, numpy-einsum

Imagine that I have integers, `n,q` and vectors/arrays with these dimensions:

```
import numpy as np
n = 100
q = 102
A = np.random.normal(size=(n,n))
B = np.random.normal(size=(q, ))

C = np.einsum("i, jk -> ijk", B, A)
D = np.einsum('ijk, ikj -> k', C, C)
```

which is working fine if all intermediate arrays fit in memory.

Now assume that I can store in memory arrays of size `(n,n)`, `(q,n)` but not any three dimensional arrays such as with shape `(n,n,q)`. I cannot store in memory array `C` above. Instead, to compute `D`,

```
D1 = np.einsum('i, jk, i, kj -> k', B, A, B, A, optimize='optimal')
```

works fine and `np.einsum` is typically smart enough to find a `einsum_path` so that no 3d array is ever constructed. Great!

Now let's complicate things slightly:

```
C = np.einsum("i, jk -> ijk", B, A)    # as before

Y2 = np.random.normal(size=(n, ))
Z2 = np.random.normal(size=(q, n))
C2 = np.einsum("j, ik -> ijk", Y2, Z2)

E = np.einsum('ijk, ikj -> k', C+C2, C+C2)
```

Here I cannot find a reasonable way (reasonable, as in short/readable code) to construct `E` without constructing intermediate 3d arrays such as C and C2.

Questions:

1. is there a `np.einsum` one liner that would construct `E`, without constructing the intermediate 3d arrays C and C2?
   The following appears to work by expanding into four terms, but is rather impractical compared to the hypothetical API in question 2...

```
E_CC   = np.einsum('i, jk, i, kj -> k', B,  A,  B,  A, optimize='optimal') # as D before
E_C2C2 = np.einsum('j, ik, k, ij -> k', Y2, Z2, Y2, Z2, optimize='optimal')
E_CC2  = np.einsum('i, jk, k, ij -> k', B,  A,  Y2, Z2, optimize='optimal')
E_C2C  = np.einsum('j, ik, i, kj -> k', Y2, Z2, B,  A, optimize='optimal')

E_new  = E_CC + E_C2C2 + E_CC2 + E_C2C 
np.isclose(E_new, E) # all True!
```

2. Is there a ''lazy'' version of `np.einsum` that would wait before the final call to find an optimal `einsum_path` throughout the composition of several lazy einsum, including sums as in the above example? For instance, with an hypothetical `einsum_lazy`, the following would construct `E` without storing a 3d array (such as C or C2) in memory:

```
C = np.einsum_lazy("i, jk -> ijk", B, A)  # nothing has been computed yet!
C2 = np.einsum_lazy("j, ik -> ijk", Y2, Z2) # nothing has been computed yet!
E = np.einsum('ijk, ikj -> k', C+C2, C+C2)  # expand the sums and uses optimal einsum_path to compute E
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a really fascinating question - as @s-m-e mentioned, numpy does not offer a lazy `einsum` computations, but it does offer a lower level function called [np.einsum_path](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum_path.html#numpy.einsum_path), which `np.einsum` uses to actually find the optimal contractions.

What if you did this:

```
C_path = np.einsum_path("i, jk -> ijk", B, A)[0]
C2_path = np.einsum_path("j, ik -> ijk", Y2, Z2)[0]
CC2_path = C_path + C2_path[1:]
```

And somehow used the path in a final computation? The biggest issue here is that you're summing C and C2, and elementwise addition is not currently supported by `einsum`, so it's hard to optimize that.

Take a look at [@Eelco Hoogendoorn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53177651/11771447)'s response to a similar question: maybe breaking it up into smaller computations isn't such a bad idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Targeting question 2:

There is no lazy version of `einsum`, unfortunately. `einsum` simply returns a numpy `ndarray` object - which is precisely what a subsequent call to `einsum` would expect as a parameter in your scenario. However, you can exploit Python itself by using [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator). In your case, the following would do the trick:

```py
C1 = (np.einsum_lazy("i, jk -> ijk", b, a) for a, b in ((A, B),))
C2 = (np.einsum_lazy("j, ik -> ijk", y2, z2) for y2, z2 in ((Y2, Z2),))

def _einsum(v, w):
    u = v + w # no need to do this twice
    return np.einsum('ijk, ikj -> k', u, u)

E = (_einsum(c1, c2) for c1, c2 in ((C1, C2),))

for e in E: # only HERE C1, C2 and E are actually computed
    print(e)
```

The above example used chained generator expressions. It's the final for loop, which triggers the actual evaluation of the chain. It's lazy, more or less. There is also another downside: From a memory perspective, C1 and C2 are in fact constructed/created (temporarily).

If memory consumption is your primary concern and if you are doing multiple similar operations, you may have a look at the `out` parameter of `einsum`. In fact, [most numpy `ufunc`s happen to have an `out` parameter](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#optional-keyword-arguments), which allows you to specify a "preexisting" numpy `ndarray` as a target for the result of the operation. Therefore, no new memory needs to be allocated, which is also speeding up your computation as a side-effect.